# SQL Oracle Combine records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns the time somebody was at work for. However this gives me multiple records for each person. Is there a way to add together the times so that i have a total time for each employee.

The query is:

```
select 
employee.first_name, 
employee.last_name, 
to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time), 'J') - 1)  days,
to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') +
(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time), 'HH24:MI:SS') time
from 
employee 
inner join 
employee_case on employee.employee_id = employee_case.employee 
inner join
time_sheet on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id 
where 
employee_case.case = 1;
```

The current output is:

[image]

but i would like to combine the Steve Baid values into 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the code still function the same without the `to_date()` calls?  I think it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to do this as nested queries:

```
select
first_name,
last_name,
to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') + (duration), 'J') - 1)  days,
to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') + (duration), 'HH24:MI:SS') time
from (
    select
    employee.first_name first_name,
    employee.last_name last_name,
    time_sheet_sum.duration duration
    from
    employee
    inner join
    (
        select
        distinct employee_case.employee_id employee_id,
        sum(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time) duration
        from
        employee_case
        inner join
        time_sheet on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id
        where
        employee_case.case = 1
        group by
        employee_case.employee_id
    ) time_sheet_sum on employee.employee_id = time_sheet_sum.employee
);
```

**NB:** I haven't been able to test or verify this code.

Comment: I am getting a not a group by expression error with this and cannot work out why. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use || to concat values like:

```
select 
employee.first_name, 
employee.last_name, 
sum (to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time), 'J') - 1))  days
from 
employee 
inner join 
employee_case on employee.employee_id = employee_case.employee 
inner join
time_sheet on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id 
where 
employee_case.case = 1;
GROUP BY employee.first_name,  employee.last_name
```

Comment: Sorry I dont think I was clear. I mean that instead of having steve baid twice. I want to have one record which has the sum of days and time as 3d 22h 39m 46s + 8d 20h 22m 13s

Comment: so you want to add days right? so it will have steve baid 11?

Comment: yes but taking into account hours minutes and seconds in the time column. so it would be something like 12 days and then time 22:01:59. So it adds it all together for the same employee for a total amount of time worked

Comment: I didnt get that time part from above hence excluded from my query. am sure you would figure that out.

Comment: do u have any tips as i am struggling to work this out?